# android opensource

Tags: android

is android fully open source????

Comment: Is this kind of discussion appropriate here?

Comment: There are some controversies that whether Android is fully open source or not, especially after Oracle sued Google mentioning that Google used proprietary Java code in its Dalvik VM (which is open source runtime for Android apps). You might get more proper answer on superuser.com or programmers.stackexchange.com, since this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "open source". The base platform is open source, lincensed under a mix of licenses. However:

- some functionality is missing from it and is available only if you sign Google license (access to the app market)
- you can't use the Android trade mark unless you sign Google license (why Nook is not marketed as Android device)
- key parts of a mobile platform are kept proprietary by Google, like Maps, and competitive solutions are actively blocked by Google (SkyHook for example)

**Update:** Google is [not releasing Honeycomb](http://www.businessweek.com/technology/content/mar2011/tc20110324_269784.htm) sources "at least for the foreseeable future"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go wild: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/Button.java&d=3

Also, really, you could not have Googled that?

Comment: Key part of Android is the AppMarket application and access to the app market. Not open source or freely available either to OEMs or end users that want to build custom OS build for their phone.

Comment: Good luck finding the Honeycomb source on there. Google is refusing to release it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes

The following links can be useful

- http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/10/25/android-open-source-or-not.html
- http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/60849

Comment: "What an open-source platform really means is that you have access to the source code which enables you to add and change anything you want and create your own definition of a variant. End users can customize Android and re-compile it within their phones with a new build. Users also can provide the binaries to their ROMs." - Creating a custom build with the same functionality as their stock Nexus S is not possible for the users without reverse engineering parts of it and tweaking with proprietary Google code. And building from the Android AOSP will severely limit the phone functionality.

Comment: which one is better  to use maemo or android as both are linux based??

Comment: @user661891 - I have no idea. It all depends on what your business goals are. Also, it is my belief that Maemo does not have much future, as there's no place for too many players in the consumer space. Though it might take a strong hold in specialized appliances...

Comment: Actually, no. :-) The followink link might be useful: http://www.businessweek.com/technology/content/mar2011/tc20110324_269784.htm